# Separate two network bridges on linux

Tags: networking, bridge, subnets

I am currently trying to setup a router for my homenetwork using linux
(Archlinux to be more specific). The embedded board i am using has 3
lan interfaces, called `wan0`, `lan0`, `lan1` and two wifi cards, called
`wifi0` and `wifi1`. I want to have two separate networks, one for my guests
and for my family and me. My current setup looks like this :

```
                   +-------+
                   | wifi0 +----------------+
                   +-------+           +----+---+
                                       |  brg0  |
                   +-------+           +----+---+
                   | eth0  +----------------+
                   +-------+


                   +-------+
                   | wifi1 +----------------+
                   +-------+           +----+---+
                                       |  brg1  |
                   +-------+           +----+---+
                   | eth1  +----------------+
                   +-------+
```

I configured a bridge containing `lan0` and `wifi0`, called `brd0`, with ip
address `192.168.10.1/24` and a bridge containing `lan1` and `wifi1`, called
`brd1`, with ip address `192.168.20.1/24`. On `brd0` as well as `brd1` dnsmasq
is running in dhcpd mode to propagate ip addresses to clients in the
range `192.168.10.50-125` for `brd0` and range `192.168.20.50-125` for
`brd1`. The `192.168.20.1/24` network is my guest network, while
`192.168.10.1/24` is my home network.

This setup works so far. However, one thing took me by surprise. I
though, because guest and home network are in two different subnets
the traffic between them is also separated. However, when i am connect
to the guest network i can also reach services and computers on the
home network, even though no static router or forwarding is set. ( the
other way around is also true). I guess this has something to do how
bridge devices work under linux.

My question is, how to configure the router so that both networks are
separated form each other? Do I need to use traffic filter rules? Can
this be implemented with etables? Or is my setup somehow broken and it
should not be possible to reach service from one network to the other?

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the text as reference, since your interface names don't match between picture and text.

The *router* is routing between all its interfaces where it has an IP, so `brd0` (home), `brd1` (guest) and `wan0` (which you forgot to add in the picture), as expected from a router.

Since you'll have later to route between `brd0` and `wan0` as well as between `brd1` and `wan0` you can't simply disable routing. You can use two iptables `FORWARD` rules to forbid this routing, one for each direction:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i brd0 -o brd1 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -i brd1 -o brd0 -j DROP
```

Should you want to have the home network have access to the guest network, but not the opposite, stateful rules can do that, using instead:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i brd1 -o brd0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i brd1 -o brd0 -j DROP
```

The first rule can probably be "factorized" with future similar rules by removing the interface names:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Note: systems from one network can still ping the router's IP belonging to the other network (eg from `192.168.20.2`, `ping 192.168.10.1` would succeed) since it's not routed, so not traversing those `FORWARD` rules, but that'd be a bit overkill to address it (with correct rules in the `INPUT` chain). I just leave it as a remark.

Note2: nothing in this answer needed to be dealing with the fact that `brd0` and `brd1` are bridges: it's all about routing.